# Convert Webform to MVC3/razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, zebra-printers

I have this example for printing the form.This example developed using webforms.

I need to implement same example in mvc3/razor, can anybody give me idea to do it?

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92

Answer (score 1):

You don't really convert from webforms to mvc in the same sense that you convert from java to c#.

First of all, the c# code in mvc can be exactly the same in your webform code behind and your mvc controller.

The difference is in where your html/code is - the model, the view, or the controller.

So for a print routine like in the sample you gave, the code doesn't need to change.

The bigger issue is that MVC, especially if you're coming from webforms, is not something most people will be immediately proficient with after a few hours.

It takes quite a lot of studying and practice to get the hang of. There is a great reward if you put in the effort, but no reward if you don't put in a good deal of effort.

To answer the question, there are many ways to achieve the same functionality, but all too verbose to describe in a short forum post - you should start from the basics of MVC at asp.net and go from there.